# How to fix Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found. Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I am getting the error `Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.` when I run the command `npm run dev` I also receive an error under this one that says `ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve` followed by a path. I am not too sure why it can't find an entry point any help would be greatly appreciated.

uploaded the whole project to github to help with visibilty.
https://github.com/dustinm94/coding-challenge

webpack.config.js

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "coding_challenge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch ./coding/frontend/src/index.js --output ./coding/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./coding/frontend/src/index.js --output ./coding/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Fix for your issue is mentioned below

`webpack.config.js` and `package.json` will always be in your project basepath and 
node commands should be triggered from this path

You must make below corrections in your `webpack.config.js` & `package.json`

#### package.json

`--watch` will automatically look for the file specified in `entry` object in `webpack.config.js` and keep watching its dependency graph to autoreload on detecting changes. You need to update your `package.json` with below details

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack" : "webpack", // invoke this command from npm run dev & npm run build
    "dev": "npm run webpack -- --mode development --watch",
    "build": "npm run webpack -- --mode production"
}
```

Running in watch mode could lead to performance issues depending on the hardware you are using, [read more about it](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/)

#### webpack.config.js

Add `entry` object to your `webpack.config.js`. If you didn't override entry object, by default, webpack points `entry` object to './src/index.js`. As you are not using default configuration in your project, webpack throws the error

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in '/root/../coding_challenge'
```

To fix the error, you need to override the `entry` object with your target `js` file as shown below

```
module.exports = {
  entry : "./frontend/src/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**if above corrections are done,**

`npm run dev` will run your project in watch mode

`npm run build` will generate production build for your project

Let me know if this info fixes your problem

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, and realised that the name `webpack.config.js` had a white space character in it.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's helped me, always recheck files names

Comment: Mine had a `-`. webpack-config.js. Thanks!